# scrapy returns 401 unauthorized response

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

site is https://www.extratodebito.detran.pr.gov.br/detranextratos/geraExtrato.do?action=iniciarProcesso

```
        yield Request(self.url, callback=self.login_me, dont_filter=True)
```

returns `<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Unauthorized</body></html>`

but if I do using requests library it's working good!

any reason why it happens ?

**UPDATE:**

normal headers looks like

```
Host: www.extratodebito.detran.pr.gov.br
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

I added it to scrapy, but I can see **Authorization** field there that was added during the request

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Basic MTM2ZGNjNmFhOWZmNDA1Njk1YWU1MWE0ZjI1MzZlYzE6
Host: www.extratodebito.detran.pr.gov.br
```

**UPDATE 2:**

solved by removing http_user and http_pass in spider that using for splash, but also sent to usual requests with scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me when adding the Accept, Accept-Language and Accept-Encoding headers.
I tested it out in `scrapy shell`:

```
headers = {'Accept': ['text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'], b'Accept-Language': ['en'], 'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip,deflate,br']}
url = "https://www.extratodebito.detran.pr.gov.br/detranextratos/geraExtrato.do?action=iniciarProcesso"
from scrapy import Request
req = Request(url, headers=headers)
fetch(req)
```

I got a 200 response:

```
2020-09-14 11:16:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-14 11:16:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.extratodebito.detran.pr.gov.br/detranextratos/geraExtrato.do?action=iniciarProcesso> (referer: None)
```

Comment: Tips: Scrapy doesn't support brotli compression. If the site you request prefer brotoli compression, scrapy can't understand the response.

Comment: I think it does (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression) - you do have to make sure Brotli is installed

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there's a optional dependency to make brotli compression work in Scrapy. @Wiim Hermans